# AWS X-Ray does not contain filter

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-xray

I have the following X-ray filter:

```
http.url CONTAINS "blah"
```

It works great, except for the fact that I want something like:

```
http.url !CONTAINS "blah"
```

The question is how do I write an X ray filter/query so the URL does not contain a specific string.

Thanks,
Brian

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this query using

```
!(http.url CONTAINS "blah")
```

Hope that works for you!

Comment: Thank you very much!